# How to delete comments by ActivityId,CommentId and UserId in Google Plus API ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-plus

I am working on Google plus Module.I already got the Comment by ActivityId of the User.But,the problem is that,I want to delete comment of a user by delete comments by ActivityId,CommentId and UserId in Google Plus API,Is it possible,If yes,then how.Please give me the full details about this.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I would suggest you read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).  While the community is very happy and willing to help, we generally expect questions to be narrow, specific, and well researched.  A question that essentially asks for code is generally not well received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently supported by the Google+ APIs. The APIs currently only allow for read operations of public data.